# Nodejs server is freaking out when I add console.print() statements to debug my javascript code in an apt.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I am trying to get information from IBM Watson during an app.get() on a NodeJs server. The code to get the information from Watson works and I am working on sending it back to the client.
But whenever I add an additional console.print( words ) it freaks out and complains about a completely different line that was fine before I added the new **console.print()** statement.

```
app.get("/text/emotion", (req,res) => {
    const nlu = getNLUInstance();
    //console.log( "request /text/emotion");
    var parameters = { text: "I am having a bad day today, \
        could someone help me please",features : {emotion: {}}}
    ret = nlu.analyze( parameters ) //, function( error, response){
           .then (analysisResults => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(analysisResults, null, 2));
            console.log( "in here")
           })
           .catch(err=> {console.log( "error",err);
           });
          
  
    console.log( ret );
    return res.send({"happy":"10","sad":"50"});
});

app.get("/text/sentiment", (req,res) => {
    return res.send("text sentiment for "+req.query.text);
});

let server = ***app.listen(8080, ()*** => {
    console.log('Listening', server.address().port);
});
```

This works, but if I add another console.log("Here") statement above console.log(ret) it freaks about about the **app.listen(8080...** call. The error points to the dot '.' between app.listen

so the code does not work

```
    console.log( "here"); 
    console.log( ret );
    return res.send({"happy":"10","sad":"50"});
});
```

but this code does

```
    console.log( ret );
    return res.send({"happy":"10","sad":"50"});
});
```

Here is the error output when the extra console.log() is added

```
[nodemon] starting `node sentimentAnalyzerServer.js`
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/project/cazgi-IBM-Watson-NLU-Project-1/sentimentAnalyzeServer/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/project/cazgi-IBM-Watson-NLU-Project-
1/sentimentAnalyzeServer**/sentimentAnalyzerServer.js:64:18)**
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 8080
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

It seems that no matter were I put the extra console.log statements that it just does not like them.
Or is there a better way to debug this stuff. I am using a terminal to do all this in.
I am very new to Node.js and javascript but this just does not seem right to me.

Comment: What is this `console.print` you speak of?  Did you mean `console.log`?  Also what is this `apt.get` you speak of?  Did you mean `app.get`?

Comment: The only error you've shown us is an EADDRINUSE, which means another process is running and is already bound to port 8080.  The rest of your problems sound like they were due to typos.  Cut and paste your actual code and actual error.